# Is there anyway to run a python script on boot up that opens terminal?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, boot

Hello I am having a difficult time running a python script on startup that request user input in terminal to name a directory. The python script ask for a file name then creates a directory and csv file to store pictures and information of each picture such as GPS data in the csv code. My code works fine when I run it in Geany but I have tried every imaginable way to start the code on bootup. The code will work if I change `direcname = str(input("name your file: "))` to  `direcname=str("file_name")`. I have spent days trying to figure this out, I can not find a single way to open terminal on boot that works for my script.

```
#import packages
from gpiozero import Button, LED
from picamera import PiCamera
import os
import datetime
from gps import *

#define gpio pins and variables
pwd = os.getcwd()
camera = PiCamera()
led = LED(13)
previewbtn = Button(26, hold_time=2) 
counter = 1

#GPS stuff
gpsd = gps(mode=WATCH_ENABLE|WATCH_NEWSTYLE) 

#make new directory and create text file within
direcname = str(input("name your file: "))
newpath = pwd + '/' + direcname
os.makedirs(newpath)
txtfile = open(newpath + '/' + direcname + '.csv', 'w+')
txtfile.write('img, date/time, lat, lon, alt(m)')
txtfile.close()

#define functions
def capture():
    global counter
    camera.capture(newpath + '/' + direcname + str(counter) + '.jpg')
    txtfile = open(newpath + '/' + direcname + '.csv', 'a')
    txtfile.write("\n")
    txtfile.write( direcname + str(counter) + ',' + str(datetime.datetime.now()) +
    ',' + lat1 + ',' + lon1 + ','+ alt1)
    txtfile.close()
    counter += 1

#run function
try:
    while True:
        #Setting lat,lon, and alt as variables
        report = gpsd.next() 
        if report['class'] == 'TPV':
            if getattr(report,'lat',0.0)!=0:
                lat1 = str(getattr(report,'lat',0.0))
            if getattr(report,'lon',0.0)!=0:
                lon1 = str(getattr(report,'lon',0.0))
            if getattr(report,'alt','nan')!= 'nan':
                alt1 = str(getattr(report,'alt','nan'))
        else:
            lat1 = "ERROR"
            lon1 = "ERROR"
            alt1 = "ERROR"
        #Everything else
        led.source = previewbtn
        previewbtn.when_pressed = camera.start_preview
        previewbtn.when_held = capture
        previewbtn.when_released = camera.stop_preview
except(KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    print("Done.\nExiting")
```

Comment: search for crontabs. I was able to automatically run py scripts on boot using it.

Comment: @Goion I have tried but it doesnt work since I need to use terminal to finish the script

Comment: Can you change the script so it doesn't rely on user input? Name you files "gps_" + `time.time()`

Comment: Why do you assume you can run a script like this during boot in the first place?  Booting is, well ... booting everything up to a state that is usable. I presume python at the earliest is available after a boot has finished.

Comment: If you are using python 3 `input()` automatically returns a string you don't need to cast it with `str()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using window manager then you can add your `python filename.py &` in `.xinitrc` which starts executing anything which is written in that script.

If using any desktop environment then it comes with a default display manager which does the same things. Each display manager has their own way of auto-starting things.

And i recommend starting it while login rather than starting on boot.